# How to initialize repository from service in Springboot Kotlin

Tags: spring-boot, api, kotlin, service, repository

```java
@Service
public class AvailablePolicyService {
    @Autowired
    private var availablePolicyRepository : AvailablePolicyRepository = **AvailablePolicyRepository()**

    fun saveAvailablePolicy(availablePolicy: AvailablePolicy): AvailablePolicy { return availablePolicyRepository.save(availablePolicy) }
    fun getAllAvailablePolicy(): List<AvailablePolicy>{ return availablePolicyRepository.findAll() }

    fun getAvailablePolicyByPolicyId(policyId: String?): AvailablePolicy? {
        var availablePolicies: List<AvailablePolicy> = getAllAvailablePolicy()
        for (availablePolicy in availablePolicies) {
            if (availablePolicy.getPolicyId().equals(policyId)) {
                return availablePolicy
            }
        }
        return null
    }

    fun getAvailablePolicyByPolicyCategory(policyCategory: String?): ArrayList<AvailablePolicy> {
        var availablePolicies: List<AvailablePolicy> = getAllAvailablePolicy()
        var availablePolicyCategory = ArrayList<AvailablePolicy>()
        for (availablePolicy in availablePolicies) {
            if (availablePolicy.getPolicyCategory().equals(policyCategory)) {
                availablePolicyCategory.add(availablePolicy)
            }
        }
        return availablePolicyCategory
    }
}
```

```java
@Repository
interface AvailablePolicyRepository : MongoRepository<AvailablePolicy, String>
```

The bolded text shows where the error is showing and it reads "Interface AvailablePolicyRepository does not have constructors". How do I initialize repository from service?

Answer (score 0):

> How do I initialize repository from service?

That's the thing. You don't! Spring does it for you:

```
@Autowired
private lateinit var availablePolicyRepository: AvailablePolicyRepository
```

Field injection is rather obsolete and you should consider using contructor injection instead.

```
@Service
class AvailablePolicyService(private val availablePolicyRepository: AvailablePolicyRepository) {...}
```